# How to display a tkinter window while using a push hardware button to capture images?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a project in which involves capturing of images. I have to display a UI while capturing an image if a button is pressed. This is the code.

```
def create_window(self):
    t = tk.Toplevel(self)
    t.geometry("480x320")
    t.wm_title("Game")
    text_file = open("players.txt", "r")
    message = text_file.read()
    self.players = message.split()

    if len(self.players) == 2:
        text_file = open("players.txt", "r")
        message = text_file.read()
        players = message.split()
        Player1 = self.players[0]  
        Player2 = self.players[1]
        player1 = tk.Label(t,
                             text=Player1,
                             font="Times 45",
                             fg="white",
                             bg="#0000FF")
        #player1.pack(side='left', padx=10, pady=10, anchor= N)
        player1.grid(row=0, column=0)
        player1.config(width=8)


        player2 = tk.Label(t,
                         text=Player2,
                         font="Times 45",
                         fg="white",
                         bg="#FF0000")

        player2.grid(row=0, column=1)
        player2.config(width=8)


        text1 = tk.Text(t, height=30, width=30)
        text1.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky='N')

        text2 = tk.Text(t, height=30, width=30)
        text2.grid(column=1, row=1, sticky='N')

        global globvar

        globvar = -1

        proc = ImageProcess()

        def my_callback(channel):  
            global time_stamp       # put in to debounce
            global globvar
            globvar += 1
            time_now = time.time()  
            if (time_now - time_stamp) >= 0.50:

                camera.capture('/home/pi/Thesis/Test/lets.jpg')
                img = cv2.imread("/home/pi/Thesis/Test/lets.jpg")

                print(proc.frame_table(img))

                player_number = globvar%len(self.players)

                print(player_number)

                pickle_in = open("game_file.pickle","rb")
                example_dict = pickle.load(pickle_in)

                if player_number == 0:
                    text1.insert(tk.INSERT,example_dict[globvar])
                if player_number == 1:
                    text2.insert(tk.INSERT,example_dict[globvar])

            time_stamp = time_now

       GPIO.add_event_detect(21, GPIO.RISING, callback=my_callback, bouncetime=500)
        time.sleep(1)
```

The code works but for some reason after I click the button it always captures the image without pressing the button. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it's pin 21 in the mode you're using? (BCM/BOARD) See [pinout.xyz](https://pinout.xyz/)

Are you sure your button is wired in a pull-down circuit (3V3->GPIO)?

A pull-up circuit (GND->GPIO) means a press triggers a falling edge and release triggers a rising edge.

You should test your button press on its own (no GUI) to see if it behaves as you expect with a simple print as your callback.

*Aside: You might find it a lot easier with [gpiozero](https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) and [guizero](https://lawsie.github.io/guizero/).*

Comment: It works fine when I try with the button itself it only print the word inside it but when I tried capturing an image after I click it always captures the image without the need of pressing the button.